# Calculating the percentage of dissociation degree

Tags: equilibrium

The question is as such:

> Notice the equilibrium expression. $$K_c=\frac{[NH_3]^2}{[N_2][H_2]^3}.$$ Initially, there were $0.28$ moles for each reactant, after it reaches equilibrium, the number mol of product produced was $0.014$ mol. What is the percentage of dissociation degree?

Through an ICE table, I calculated the number of mol of $N_2$, $H_2$, and $NH_3$ at equilibrium. There are $0.273$ mol of $N_2$ ($0.007$ mol is used), $0.259$ mol of $H_2$ ($0.021$ mol is used), and $0.014$ mol of $NH_3$, but I'm not sure how to calculate the percentage of dissociation degree.

My teacher taught that $\alpha=\dfrac{n_{\text{change}}}{n_{\text{initial}}}$ (referring to the ICE table), but I'm not sure which $n$ to use. Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It is not a dissociation degree. It looks like a copy-pasted term from acid-base equilibrium context. // The equation uses amount concentrations, but there are provides amounts, not their concentrations.

Comment: That's where I got confused. I thought dissociation degree/degree of ionisation is used in acid-base context, but I'm not sure about this one. My teacher also said that whenever the volume isn't mentioned in the question, we are to use $V = 1L$. I'm sorry that I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

For a reaction of the form:

$$\ce{aA +bB<=>cC +dD}$$

You can calculate the dissociation fraction $\alpha$ using its relationship with $K_C$:

$$K_C=\frac{\left(\frac{C_{Co}}{C_{Ao}}+\frac{c}{a}\alpha\right)^c\;\left(\frac{C_{Do}}{C_{Ao}}+\frac{d}{a}\alpha\right)^d}{\left(1-\alpha\right)^a\;\left(\frac{C_{Bo}}{C_{Ao}}-\frac{b}{a}\alpha\right)^b}\;\left(C_{Ao}\right)^{\Delta n}$$

In your case, the relevant reaction is:

$$\ce{3H2(g) + N2(g)<=>2NH3(g)}$$

Where:

$\ce{H2}$ is the limiting reagent A

$\ce{N2}$ is B

$\ce{NH3}$ is C

Using the molar balance equation for $\ce{NH3}$, you can calculate the change in moles $x$ that takes place after equilibrium is reached:

$$N_C=N_{Co}+cx\implies x=\frac{N_C-N_{Co}}{c}=\frac{0.014-0}{2}=0.007$$

Substituting $x$ into the molar balances of $A$ and $B$:

$$N_A=N_{Ao}-ax=0.28-3x=0.259$$

$$N_B=N_{Bo}-bx=0.28-x=0.273$$

Since it is mentioned that volume is $\pu{1L}$, all amounts are equal to their respective concentrations, and we can calculate $K_C$:

$$K_C=\frac{C_C^c}{C_A^a\;C_B^b}=\frac{N_C^c}{N_A^a\;N_B^b}=\frac{(0.014)^2}{(0.259)^3(0.273)}=0.04132$$

By simplifying and using the equation that relates $K_C$ and $\alpha$, we can calculate the latter:

$$K_C=\frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}\alpha\right)^2}{\left(1-\alpha\right)^3\;\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\alpha\right)}\;\left(0.28\right)^{-2}=0.04132$$

Solving for $\alpha$:

$$\alpha=0.075$$

Or equivalently:

$$\alpha=7.5\%$$

Alternatively, you can also use your teacher's equation, although I would argue it's incomplete since it does not account for the molar coefficient $a$ of the limiting reagent A. The complete form would be:

$$\alpha=\frac{ax}{C_{Ao}}$$

We can verify we get the same result:

$$\alpha=\frac{(3)(0.007)}{0.28}=0.075=7.5\%$$

However, the wording of the problem is in conflict with the definition of $\alpha$, since $\ce{NH3}$ should be dissociating into its constituent gases from a non-zero initial amount with no initial amounts of $\ce{H2}$ or $\ce{N2}$ present, not vice-versa.

Perhaps your teacher overlooked this when designing the problem.